# How to loop through multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I have an array that looks something like this:

```
Array
(
    [apple] => Array
        (
            [0] => 689795
            [1] => September 2012
            [2] => 689795
            [3] => September 2012
            [4] => 1113821
            [5] => June 2013
            [6] => 1122864
            [7] => July 2013
        )

    [pear] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1914898
            [1] => September 2012
            [2] => 1914898
            [3] => September 2012
            [4] => 1914646
            [5] => September 2012
            [6] => 1914898
            [7] => September 2012
        )
)
```

What I want to do is loop through the "apple" element and output something like this:

```
['September 2012', 689795],
['September 2012', 689795],
['June 2013', 1113821],
['July 2013', 1122864],
```

How can I accomplish this? So my main goal is to organize the dates and values together.

My array data is much longer than the example above, but I just need help in order to get a working code to loop through and echo something like the example above.

I've tried using `foreach`, however I can't get it to work. I'm fairly new to PHP.

Comment: By using nested loops

Comment: `reset` & 2 `each()` calls in a loop seems handy oldschool, `foreach(array_chunk($array['apple'],2) as $combo){}` is also a possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use array_chunk for something like this, probably the smallest and cleanest code.

```
foreach (array_chunk($arr['apple'], 2) as $row) {
    echo "['$row[1]', $row[0]],<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
foreach ($first_array as $first_key=>$first_val) {
    foreach ($first_val as $second_key=>$second_val){
        echo $second_val;
    }
}
```

This will loop over your first array. Then for each value you get from the first loop (which is your nested array), you do the for loop again.

Now your $second_val is your "key" first time and "date" the second time.

Answer (score 2):

If your 'inner' array has always 8 elements, use an outer `foreach` to iterate through the fruits and a inner `for` loop:

```
foreach ($array as $fruit) {

    for ($i == 1; $i <= 7; $i += 2) {

        echo $fruit[$i] . ", " . $fruit[$i-1] . "<br />";

    } // for
} // foreach
```